# Inconsistency between shown and returned value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables: User and Warpable

the relation between them is as:

user `has_many :warpables` and warpable `belongs_to :user`

The @warpable is showing correct value of user_id but when I use @warpable.user_id then I get different result:

[image]

I know, I am missing something but can't figure out the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: can you show the query where @warpable is assigned?